# Intentionally delay on loading screen (setTimeout?)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, apple-tv, tvml

In my tvOS app, before a template is shown, a loadingtemplate is coming up.
But: It is only seen for like *.50 seconds*, since I push it away immediatly with the main templates. How can I delay that, so its showing for *2-3 seconds*, and then proceed to push my actual main template on the screen.

```
function loadingTemplate() {
  var loadingDoc = "<document> ... </document>";
  //parsing it as an xml 
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var parsedTemplate = parser.parseFromString(loadingDoc, "application/xml");
  return parsedTemplate;
}
```

Other functions will now call it like this at the very beginning:

```
var loadingDocument = loadingTemplate();
navigationDocument.pushDocument(loadingDocument);
```

Then the code is following and the main documents are pushing the loadingDocument away.

I tried to do something like this :

```
setTimeout(function() { navigationDocument.pushDocument(loadingDocument);}, 9000);
```

But can't really get it to work. Someone any idea?

Edit : Tried to push the loading document on screen , and then delaying the setTimeout on the following whole code. Not working tho how i did it :/

Comment: What you are saying is: "I want to ruin user experience by showing loader for 3 seconds even if page has loaded in no time, because I can.". Three seconds is quite long waiting time nowadays. If i were you I'd implement mechanism that show loader template only when rendering template takes longer than some small amount of time (e.g. 500ms, depending on your case).

Comment: Yea i realized, 3 seconds is quite long. The thing is, i only want to have it on the start of the app. And its not saying like : loading  (+ spinner), but the name of the app and some informations.

Answer (score 0):

This will delay you default template with 2s:

```
clearTimeout(window.resizedFinished);
    window.resizedFinished = setTimeout(function() {
        /* default template */
    }, 2000);
```